# Regarding interpretation of Surah Tin (non-mention of other trees such as oak and cedar)

Tags: tafseer, surah

By the fig and the olive. And [by] Mount Sinai. And [by] this secure city [Makkah].

Fig corresponds to Mt Sinai. Olive is considered Makkah.

However, there are other sacred trees mentioned in Torat, Injil.

Trees like oak, aspen, cedar trees of Lebanon (which becomes Sidratul Muntaha in quran).

Has anyone in history interpreted this surah the way i have? That is my question.

Comment: This sounds a bit far fetched.

Comment: Makkah instead of Jabal Nur.

Comment: There are no olive trees in Makkah. However there are olive trees in Jerusalem. Points to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has been narrated as the interpretation of **التين** and **الزيتون** respectively:

- The fruits that we eat: Fig and Olive
- Shaam and Palestine
- The mosque of Noah at Mount Judi and Bayt al-Maqdis
- Masjid al-Haram and Masjid al-Aqsa
- Damascus and Bayt al-Maqdis
- Damascus and Palestine
- The Mosque of the Companions of the Cave and the Mosque of Jerusalem
- A mountain in Damascus and Bayt al-Maqdis

Reference: [الدر المنثور](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12884/7171#p1)